# Energy of photon given temperautre

Tags: energy, photons

I have a question asking to find the energy of a photon emitted from mater of temperature $T$. If the question had asked frequency, it would have clearly been that $E_{photon}=h\cdot f$. I do know that classically, the energy of an oscillator is $E = K_{b} \cdot T$. Is it okay to use this formula for this question?

Comment: To me it sounds like it wants you to assume blackbody radiation

Comment: Is there a way to relate the frequency of an emitted photon to the temperature of the mater it was emitted from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the physics of blackbody radiation, [Wien's displacement law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law) states that the peak (i.e. most probable) wavelength of radiation from a perfect blackbody at temperature $T$ is given by

$\lambda_{peak} = \frac{2.898 ×10^{-3} m⋅K}{T}$

From the wavelength you can, of course, calculate the frequency and therefore the energy.

I am making an assumption that this probably wants you to make the approximation that the object is close to a perfect blackbody, and that you've probably measured more than just "one photon" so you actually know the most common photon wavelength coming out.